# Deep emptiness (nothingness) while meditating

Tags: meditation, vipassana, sunyata

When meditating mom claims that she enters in to deep emptiness and she would reside in that emptiness for the whole period. She also says she can’t even feel her breath or her self. She’s bit lost ATM. Any suggestions on this? Any reference preferably in Sinhalese if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your mom is well and healthy, your description fits with the buddhist perception of emptiness (sunyata). It's not dangerous, and the experiences could be the result of a progressed concentration thanks to meditation.

In short, sunyata can be described as a state during meditation - just like you described it - but it also has connections to a way of perceiving the world, in a general sense.

Below is a link that discusses the phenomenon, as well as referring to relevant suttas:

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.122.than.html

(Perhaps an online translation service can help to display this content in sinhala)

Lastly, an unsolicited advice would be to consult a buddhist monastery, where you might be able to recieve some more substantial guidance from experienced practicioners.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe arupa jhana, a state of formless internal absorbtion based on intellect purified of the five bodily senses, that is if really isn't percepient of bodily sensations, lights & forms, it is a big if tho.

Good for her but should not be negligent of the development of the knowledge faculty.

Should also try delineating factors of that state, lest she is abiding in the highest release there will be a multitude of delineation and i doubt she is abiding in the highest release given that she is perplexed about these things. If it is an arupa jhana then there is no thought but emerging from the state one can think about it.

Comment: You can refer to the Sutta mn43, sn36.11, mn26, mn128 and mn59. Just google the reference and look up a sinhala translation

Comment: Bahuvedaniya, Ariyapariyesana, Rahogata, Mahavedalla and the Upakilesa Sutta are the titles.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mom is falling asleep & taking a break from family duties & burdens.

Comment: Lol so true, she doubts that too
